# Operation time out for EC2 instance open to all

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I can't seem to ssh into my ec2 instance and I am not sure why. I am on the free tier and with all my attempts, I'm not sure why I am constantly getting Operation Timeout

I am using this command

`ssh -i /path/to/keypair.pem ec2-user@public_dns_name`

My security group for outbound and inbound has Port Range set to ALL, traffic is ALL, Protocol is ALL, and IP 0.0.0.0/0

When I SSH, I keep getting Operation Timeout. I have the instance set to accept all traffic and yet I cannot SSH into it. I've terminated an instance and created another one but same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct IP address or DNS name for the server? Have you double checked that in the console to make sure it hasn't changed?

Comment: @MarkB yes I am sure. I've checked several times before you commented and several times after. Still hanging... tried `-vvv` as well http://postimg.org/image/9plbtbgsb/   http://dpaste.com/32A7BH4

Comment: Post the `ssh -vvv` output. Are you sure there is an SSH service listening? This is a Linux server, right?

Comment: @MarkB http://dpaste.com/32A7BH4  ssh -vvv. I am using the Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: Is the instance in a VPC, and if so, is the network ACL also open for the subnet and port?

Comment: @KarenB Pretty new to this but yes there is a VPC ID and also a Subnet ID. I'm not sure where to check if the network ACL is open for the subnet and port

Comment: If you're using the Console, get the subnet ID for the instance, then get the network ACL ID for that subnet, and then you can view the existing rules for that network ACL.

Comment: @KarenB I found the subnet ID but I'm not sure where to look for the ACL ID

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#ACLSubnet

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to connect to an instance unless the instance both has a public/elastic IP, and is also located in a public subnet.